# Maven : Get rid of older dependency

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a maven based project called XYZ which has following dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupid>com.example.test</groupid>
  <artifactId>PQR</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This PQR dependency has other maven dependency ABC of version 1.2
When I use XYZ as dependency in another project, i want to use ABC version 1.4.

I tried following:
1) changing order of dependency:(explicitly adding ABC 1.4 dependency)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.exampe.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupid>com.example.test</groupid>
  <artifactId>PQR</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Excluding ABC from PQR

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.exampe.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupid>com.example.test</groupid>
  <artifactId>PQR</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
  <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <artifactId>com.exampe.test</artifactId>
       <groupId>ABC</groupId>
     </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Both of this doesnt work.
I still get version 1.2 in when I use XYZ as dependency.
How can I get this right?

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution is one (correct) possibility. Version numbers in direct dependencies always win. If it does not work for you, you probably have made a mistake (wrong groupId, did not rebuild or update, etc.)

Another, more elegant solution would be to add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.exampe.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>  
</dependency>
```

to your `<dependencyManagement>` section.